# PLU (LUP) decomposition failed with zeros on main diagonal

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, math, matrix

I am trying to write [PLU (LUP) decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) using Gaussian elimination. I found [this article](https://johnfoster.pge.utexas.edu/numerical-methods-book/LinearAlgebra_LU.html) with this algorithm:

```
def plu(A):
    
    #Get the number of rows
    n = A.shape[0]
    
    #Allocate space for P, L, and U
    U = A.copy()
    L = np.eye(n, dtype=np.double)
    P = np.eye(n, dtype=np.double)
    
    #Loop over rows
    for i in range(n):
        
        #Permute rows if needed
        for k in range(i, n): 
            if ~np.isclose(U[i, i], 0.0):
                break
            U[[k, k+1]] = U[[k+1, k]]
            P[[k, k+1]] = P[[k+1, k]]
            
        #Eliminate entries below i with row 
        #operations on U and #reverse the row 
        #operations to manipulate L
        factor = U[i+1:, i] / U[i, i]
        L[i+1:, i] = factor
        U[i+1:] -= factor[:, np.newaxis] * U[i]
        
    return P, L, U
```

With normal matrix it's running well but when on main diagonal appears 0 it breaks. For example with this matrix:

```
[[1,  0,  26, 10],
 [60, 0,  75, 50],
 [45, 90, 31, 100],
 [30, 45, 10, 0]]
```

```
P
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
L
[[ 1.  0.   0.          0.]
 [60.  1.   0.          0.]
 [45.  0.   1.          0.]
 [30.  0.5  0.13501684  1.]]
U
[[1.  0.   26.     10.        ]
 [0.  90.  -1139.  -350.        ]
 [0.  0.   -1485.  -550.        ]
 [0.  0.   0.      -50.74074074]]
```

Multiplication of `PLU` will not give the original matrix.

So I tried to fix the algorithm: when rows swapping they are swapping only in `P` and `U`, so I add `L[[k, k + 1]] = L[[k + 1, k]]` in the inner loop to swap it in the `L` too. Also I changed the initialization of `L`: in the start I fill L with zeros `L = np.zeros_like(A)` and add identity matrix in the end `L += np.eye(n, dtype=np.double)`.

But fixed version of algorithm give wrong result when top left element is 0. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would go with Numerical Recipes instead of a Wikipedia article: http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/NumericalRecipiesInC/c2-3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think I fix it.

```
def get_plu_decomposition(A):
    n = A.shape[0]
    U = csr_matrix(A.copy())
    L = csr_matrix(np.zeros_like(A))
    P = csr_matrix(np.eye(n, dtype=np.double))

    for i in range(n - 1):
        index = np.argmax(abs(U[i:, i]))
        if not U[i:, i][index] != 0:
            continue
        index += i
        if index != i:
            U[[index, i]] = U[[i, index]]
            P[[index, i]] = P[[i, index]]
            L[[index, i]] = L[[i, index]]
        factor = U[i + 1:, i] / U[i, i]
        L[i + 1:, i] = factor
        U[i + 1:] -= factor * U[i]

    L += csr_matrix(np.eye(n, dtype=np.double))
    P = P.transpose()

    assert (np.allclose(A, (P@L@U).toarray()))

    return P, L, U
```

The problem was in swapping rows and transposing P matrix